# Should password be set by users without security check?

Tags: password, security, users

I'm guessing if I should let my users choose their password without checking if there's at least 1 $pecial charact€r, 1 CAPLOCK, 1 numb3r...

Shouldn't we just ask users to put a minimum of X characters (6 or 8?) and let them choose their level of security?

Comment: If you want to do "levels of security", at least [do it right](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: Added a bounty because I'm very interested in detailed, well-sourced, answers on this topic.

Comment: Implied in the question is that you will be calculating and displaying to the user the actual level of security?  Along lines of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength#Entropy_as_a_measure_of_password_strength  (last word https://xkcd.com/936/ :)

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/16433/687). You can see [my answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/16499/687) to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several things to consider here:

**firstly is the way human beings create passworsds:**

Firstly, users will just append a 1 or an ! to their favourite insecure dictionary password, or capitalise the first letter. This is a human trait called satificing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisficing#Decision_making). This human behaviour of aiding memory while just satisfying the rules immediately renders the 'x xxx xxx years of a desktop processor to crack' calculations nonsensical.

Secondly, you provide a mental hurdle for the user when they come back to get into your site again as the password they use for everything that isn't too serious is not working. All you've then done is given the user an extra conscious thought and possible mistake to overcome to get back into your site. This is the against the essential premise of 'Don't make me think' by Steve Krug.

You also have the added problem of obfuscation, as virtually all password fields are starred out all of the time, so visual memory is also taken out of the equation.

So your user is never going to use '642HfD77sk*7' they are going to use 'madonna1#' or '!sarah1957' or something else memorable and personal. You could probably brute force an account belonging to a close person like a parent by hand with a spreadsheet and a day or two, even if the passwords required numbers and special characters. 
Here are some examples of popular passwords from recent database hacks ... http://netforbeginners.about.com/od/scamsandidentitytheft/tp/The-Most-Common-Passwords-2011.htm  and again, from an attack on Adobe: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-24821528 ... the same group that selected 'adobe123' en masse is not suddenly going to select a random string of keyboard symbols if required to use numbers and special characters.

this article discusses some of these points also: https://medium.com/building-things-on-the-internet/a0c3eb525200

**next is the number of possible types of attack you negate with the use of a strong password**

There are many security issues with websites ... three immediate examples, that will gain passwords, are database breaches where millions of passwords are stolen in one go from the source; social engineering, where the user (or their representative) hands the password over without realising it; and phishing / spoofing, where the user is convinced they are using something legitimate when they are not. Not to mention that many people keep a list of password in their wallets / on their desks at home, waiting to be physically stolen. Then we get into the other possible security breaches, like unscrupulous employees, XSS and CSRF, so by insisting on a secure password you are not negating a great deal of potential risks.

**The next consideration is how secure does your site have to be**

Following on from @BennySkogberg's answer, **where serious security is required the developers do take responsibility for the security of their users - and so must you**.

Services like paypal and online banks, who protect serious information, use many other sophisticated ways of protecting your account. They **monitor alsorts of other things**, like the purchases I make, and will lock the account down in the case of suspicious transactions. In these cases the password is not a large part of the security - it basically stops opportunist access from others using the same devices as me. They still require special chars, but considering the first point it's obvious that they have other ways of stopping any brute force attack.

**So, in conclusion:**

When you put these three points together it is obvious that it isn't really necessary. If you are storing serious data about someone then you have many other threats and should have many other tactics up your sleeve (though you probably should still enforce in order to look secure and avoid bad PR), if not then you shouldn't increase the cognitive load on the repeat visiting human. In almost all cases making things nicer for the repeat visiting human should come out on top.

But, if you must do it, then you please also **publish a reminder of your password rules on your login screen**, i.e. 'we made you pick a password with at least one special character', allow the password to be created and entered in plain text and **provide very good password reset**.

Comment: Best answer in terms of listing articles and backing up claims. Bounty awarded.

Answer (score 19):

High password entropy protects against brute forcing passwords. It does not protect against any other attack against passwords. Your first task should be to ensure that the passwords will not get stolen from your servers and that you have proper timeouts. With regard to password policies my stance is as follows:

1. Do not store passwords in plain text. If you store encrypted passwords ensure that they are salted.
2. Do not force your user any special characters since you do not know what keyboard they have.
3. Do not prevent your users from any special characters and do not artifically restrict the length of the passwords. If I chose I need a high entropy password then the site must not restrict me. 100 characters should always suffice.
4. If you want to enforce high entropy implement an entropy estimator and check versus the entropy.
5. Do not have trivial fallback questions for lost passwords (e.g. mother's maiden name). If you need to have fallback questions ensure that users can create their own.
6. If you need elevated security forget about passwords as the only security measure. Passwords are very easy to circumvent no matter how long they are.
7. Add an option to make the password visible while typing. If a user is sure nobody is watching, why make it harder to verify if the password is properly entered?

Comment: Great points, but would be nice if you linked to sources or studies. Your answer seems more like a summary of a good answer.

Comment: My standard source is "Security Engineering" by Ross Anderson. In this case I recommend chapter 3 and 4: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/Papers/SE-03.pdf and https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/Papers/SEv2-c04.pdf Especially the two introductionary quotes of chapter 4 apply here ;)

Comment: The other source is more funny but a good summary: http://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: Actually @udo I also like this one: http://xkcd.com/538/

Comment: There is another more specifc source that I forgot to mention: http://www.jbonneau.com/doc/2012-jbonneau-phd_thesis.pdf

Comment: One more source: https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/458857/Password_guidance_-_simplifying_your_approach.pdf

Comment: What if the users creates a trivial fallback question (mother's maiden name...)? Is it safer to let the users to pick 3 out of pool of questions?

Answer (score 9):

You are responsible for the security of your site! Not your users. That’s why you determine how high security level on passwords your site requirements demand. If its $pecial Ch@racters, Num83r5, length of password, UPPER CASE or lower case. You decide, not your users. They shouldn’t determine security level against dictionary lookup password attacks – you do.

In an empirical study this morning I tried three different passwords on the site **[How secure is my password?](https://howsecureismypassword.net)**, which illustrates the importance of characters and length. On first trial I used one of the worlds most common passwords **1234**

[image]

If I let my users use this password, I would leave there account wide open to anyone. Not a really good option. So I tried another combination which IT departments often use provide first time passwords to new users. The password **Winter2014!** gives this acceptable result

[image]

Six years for a computer, that's quite nice. But if we throw in a whole semtenece? With only lower case letters? Let's try **whatisthematrix**

[image]

13'000 years? For a computer? Very nice. Password length is obviously critical!

And if we replace i with 1, a with 4 and s with $, leaving us with the following password **wh4t1$them4tr1x** - this is the result:

[image]

No comment needed.

## More technical notes

Consider the [following answer (by Tom Leak)](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/33471) to the question form our sister site Information Security: [What technical reasons are there to have low maximum password lengths?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33470/what-technical-reasons-are-there-to-have-low-maximum-password-lengths)

> Take five chimpanzees. Put them in a big cage. Suspend some bananas from the roof of the cage. Provide the chimpanzees with a stepladder. BUT also add a proximity detector to the bananas, so that when a chimp goes near the banana, water hoses are triggered and the whole cage is thoroughly soaked.
>
> Soon, the chimps learn that the bananas and the stepladder are best ignored.
>
> Now, remove one chimp, and replace it with a fresh one. That chimp knows nothing of the hoses. He sees the banana, notices the stepladder, and because he is a smart primate, he envisions himself stepping on the stepladder to reach the bananas. He then deftly grabs the stepladder... and the four other chimps spring on him and beat him squarely. He soon learns to ignore the stepladder.
>
> Then, remove another chimp and replace it with a fresh one. The scenario occurs again; when he grabs the stepladder, he gets mauled by the four other chimps -- yes, including the previous "fresh" chimp. He has integrated the notion of "thou shalt not touch the stepladder".
>
> Iterate. After some operations, you have five chimps who are ready to punch any chimp who would dare touch the stepladder -- and none of them knows why.
>
> ---
>
> Originally, some developer, somewhere, was working on an old Unix system from the previous century, which used the old DES-based "crypt", actually a password hashing function derived from the DES block cipher. In that hashing function, only the first eight characters of the password are used (and only the low 7 bits of each character, as well). Subsequent characters are ignored. That's the banana.
>
> The Internet is full of chimpanzees.

## Conclusion

So what do we do? It's irresponsible of us to compromise safety, and at the same time we need to make the site accessible and useful bringing he best user experience to our visitors. If we cannot implement a third party login option (Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, and OpenID) which would be the best option - I'd suggest the following:

- We chose level of security, not our users.
- If a user uses lowercase only characters, the minimum length would be 12 characters.
- If a user uses at least one character in upper case, numbers or symbols, the minimum length would be 10 characters.
- If a user uses at least two characters in either upper case, numbers or symbols and not two of the same, the minimum length would be eight characters.

This would be a delicate compromise between security and user experience.

Comment: What's the difference between "passwordnotindictionary" and "passwordnotindictionary!@#" in terms of security?  Not a whole lot.  What's the difference in terms of UX?  The former is easier to remember since it is one of a handful of passwords I commonly use, making the later an inconvenience.

Comment: @cimmanon True! But don't leave the choise to your users. You're responsible for security, not them. If you find only password length enough security level, go ahead and implement!

Comment: You could also use this site for checking password strength: https://passfault.appspot.com/password_strength.html. Not that the one you linked is bad, but this one checks more things. Other than that, excellent answer.

Comment: @Luke Thanks! I know my link is more illustrative than technical, just to show what difference it makes. Thanks for the link, I appreciate it!

Comment: As a pure security issue I would agree with you, but from a UX perspective I'm not so sure. OK, the user experience of getting your account compromised is pretty negative, but so too is having to remember a multitude of passwords because each site has their own password rules (must contain upper case, be between 8-15 letters, must contain a number, special character and name of a Shakespere play...) For instance, I have a password algorithm I use and amend it for each site it's used on, but some sites won't let me use the one I determine so I need to pick a less-secure one due to their rules.

Comment: @cimmanon have you just announced one of your actual passwords that you use? "it is one of a handful of passwords I commonly use"

Comment: @DaveHaigh Of course not, that would be silly.  It's just an example of how I circumvented the ridiculous password requirements for my SE account:  it is one of my usual passwords (all of which contain at least one word not found in the dictionary) with `!@#` tacked on the end.

Comment: Brute forcing above a very low level should not be a factor in security user experience - there should be technical measures that prevent this from happening. (Unless your password DB gets stolen, but then you have bigger problems...) The burden should not be passed onto the user.

The more likely attack is password/email pairs being stolen from other sites. Helping the user understand more about why (if?) they need a unique password is the best defense here.

Comment: I agree with the idea of estimating strength instead of fixed rules, but the strength estimator in the example sucks. `Winter2014!` certainly falls into the `Instantly` category, and `whatisthematrix` is very weak as well. Even `wh4t1$them4tr1x` isn't *that* great, password crackers contain leet-speak conversion rules.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I really doubt you've cracked many passwords, having some personal experience in the matter Winter2014! is not instantaneous even with GPU acceleration. whatisthematrix would take 1.677e21 guesses.... If you want to do a dictionary crack assuming you know that there are words with no capitals with no spaces (which is a big assumption) it reduces your search space to roughly 1e16 given a small dictionary file of 10000 words. Password cracking is much much harder than you think, but easier than the public thinks :P.

Comment: `whatisthematrix` may take a lot time to guess when you try to build it from words. But it's a very popular quote, there is even a website called `whatisthematrix.com`. An attacker mining popular quotes for their dictionary should be able to figure out that one out withing acceptable time. How long it actually takes obviously depends on the hash, but `Winter2014!` should be around 20-25 bits of strength, which are a couple of seconds with a mediocre hash.

Comment: @JonW I've edited my answer and added a conclusion which could address the user experience side of the problem.

Comment: @BennySkogberg: Yes, I agree it's a difficult balance. I also wonder if that, by setting requirements like this, you're basically giving crackers some rules to follow with their crack process ("Ah, this site needs Uppercase, special characters and be over 10 characters long... That means I can discard certain processes of my cracking")!

Comment: @JonW The general rule in security is "If it's online, it's note safe". You can't protect yourself agains the threat. The idea is to make it just hard enough so it's not worth the trouble. Pretty much like the defence policy of Sweden. We can't protect ourselves from Putin, but we can make it har enough that it's not worth the trouble to invade Sweden.

Comment: Make your password story. Like an alien brings you an apple from their stars which is 12000 light years far away and . Possible password: AlienApple*1200Light . I think that it is the best way - You can remember but for machine it is hard.

Answer (score 3):

Users should be **encouraged** rather than forced to pick a strong password.  A minimum length of 6-8 characters is fairly standard practice and most people are used to it by now.  Forcing the user to follow arbitrary rules, such as *must include at least one uppercase letter and one special character* only serve to frustrate users who are capable of choosing a secure enough password on their own that does not follow the dictated pattern.  If I'm signing up for a message board, the level of security I want is quite different from what I want for my bank account.  Don't make me use a bank strength password for a message board.

According to [How secure is my password?](https://howsecureismypassword.net/), a password such as "myreallysecurepassword" would take 106 trillion years to crack, while a password such as "password12" would only take 10 days and "Password1!" would take 58 years years.  They also warn against the use of common passwords such as *password* and *password1*.

If you're allowing an attacker to sit there and brute force an account for 10 days, password strength is the least of your concerns (these people are costing you money and sapping server resources).  Authentication needs to be throttled, such as locking the account for 5-10 minutes after a certain number of incorrect guesses.  Unless the user does not have access to the email address that's associated with their account, using the password recovery feature would be faster for them than to continue guessing passwords.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/936/ - the second paragraph in cartoon form :-)

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote about [designing for security fatigue](http://blog.edeverett.co.uk/2014/01/thoughts-on-designing-for-security-fatigue/) that addresses this question somewhat.

> Shouldn't we [...] let them choose their level of security?

Emphatically no. As the site owner/designer you must understand the minimum level of security needed to protect your users.* If you are storing credit card details of personal information this level might be quite high, if you are asking people to log in so you can personalised their experience the required security level can be low.

Users will generally not fully understand the security risks involved in an account being hacked and how the information gained could be used to hack other more important services, so if you want your users to choose the level of security they are comfortable with (above the minimum that you have set) then you must do something to educate them about the risks.

*There are potential legal implications if you around data protection legislation and PCI requirements if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with people choosing and remembering good passwords is one of psychology.  Passwords are scary and confusing, because people are afraid to write them down, and they're hard to remember when they have to have letters and numbers and symbols.  Instead of prompting your users to choose a short and complex password, consider this question:

```
Please choose a pass phrase of at least four words and type it here:
```

It eliminates the scary wording of "password".  It makes it friendly and human accessible.  And you can enforce it by requiring the entered string be at least 16 characters long - which, if someone was actually using a secure password, would be a fairly safe length.

Comment: The problem here is that if you don't tell users that this input will be their password, they'll probably write gibberish and will not be able to remember it. If you tell them upfront that this is a password, they'll know that they'll have to choose wisely so that it can be remembered.

Comment: @jff: as anectodal evidence, I recall a user trying to use PGP years and years ago, and, to cut a story short, failing because being asked for a "mantra" didn't make sense to them in context, which is what PGP used to call its passphrase.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would argue that the bigger problem isn't user account password but rather admin as those are the ones that get cracked and then expose thousands of accounts and passwords. I would then argue that social engineering attacks will expose many users data because birthrates and last 4 of social really are easy to find if someone targets you specifically.

If you implement protections such as lockouts after 3 false attempts, wouldn't you discourage the majority of user account attacks? Implement 2-step verification and you reduce attacks even more. You could add something like an image check similar to what Bank of America does just to add more protection. With cracking techniques [Ars Technica Article](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/03/how-i-became-a-password-cracker/) many passwords that are based on dictionary words will be discovered very quickly as well as thousands that have proven popular over the years.

Lastly, educate your users about security when they are setting their passwords. Remind them not to use recovery questions that are easily found on Facebook or from their trashcans. Encourage them to use a tool like 1Password to help make all of their accounts secure because they probably reuse a few strong passwords that then means any crack on any site exposes them all.

Answer (score 0):

**“Be Secure or Be Sued”**
*Silicon.com, 16 Nov 2000*

Not only you should force users to choose a secure password but also you should keep them updated with security messages/warnings. *Why?* Because if somethings goes wrong then ***you are the one which is responsible.***

Let me give you some examples.

At February 8th 2000, Yahoo! was under a DDoS attack. And, here is the court result for Yahoo!:

*“There is a distinct probability that if your site has been hijacked for a denial of service attack, then you could be liable for damages. I would definitely advise clients they have grounds to sue.”

Nick Lockett, e-commerce lawyer at Sidley & Austin*

Or the German bank which was sentenced for a fraud based on DES.

You can find similar examples whole over the Internet.

Comment: Can you at least link to the examples and cite where the sources are from? I don't want to look "[all] over the Internet".

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Benny Skogberg. You are responsible for the security of your site. But not by forcing users to use $pecial PASSw0rds. You must provide sufficient infrastructure to avoid brute force attacks on any user account.

In normal attacks there is an IP address that try hundreds of password to crack an account. So you can simply block that IP address. But in extended attacks such as DOS there is a lot of IP address that try to crack an account. So blocking an IP address is not sufficient. In this case you can detect the attack on a account. And then restrict access to that account (e.g users required to enter a catpcha code).